# ¿Relación redundante?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, relaciones

tengo una base de datos ya diseñada y funcionando, sin embargo, me preocupa saber si el enfoque que estoy utilizando tiene sentido.

En mi base de datos tengo dos entidades Usuarios y Compañías, donde una compañía pertenece a un usuario, pero a su vez esa compañía tiene muchos usuarios empleados (incluyendo al usuario dueño de la compañía)

Actualmente tengo la relación de esta manera:

- La compañía pertenece a un usuario.
- Y muchos usuarios pertenecen a una compañía.

¿Sin embargo esto no sería redundante? Ya que un usuario puede ser dueño de compañía (relación uno a uno con usuario-compañía) y el usuario es a su vez empleado de la compañía (relación uno a muchos compañía-usuario).

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de aplicar esta relación?
Cabe destacar que es totalmente necesario saber quien es el dueño de la compañía.

Comment: Saludos. Creo que alli depende como este `Usuario` y `Compañia`; si directamente estan alli las `PK` de una como `FK` a la otra ¿cual crear primero? marcara error. Ahora si es en otra tabla donde usas esas `PK` como `FK` y solo agregas una bandera para marcar al dueño no le veo inconveniente (este es un escenario, no el ideal, idoneo o algo parecido, es ejemplo/un decir).

Comment: Necesitas una tercera tabla `usuario_compania` para expresar la relación. En esa tabla habrá al menos dos columnas: `id_usuario, id_compania` y podría haber otra columna `id_cargo` que enlazaría con otra tabla `cargo` donde identificarías valores como: `propietario, vigilante, mensajero, secretaria, contable,` etc.

Comment: ¿No puedes establecerlo como una relación 1 a muchos, donde el usuario contenga la llave foránea de la compañía y también un campo booleano que indique si es jefe? Así tendrías a qué compañía pertenece el usuario y si el campo booleano es verdadero, entonces indica que es el jefe de la compañía a la que está relacionado, si no (si es falso), entonces es un empleado más de la misma.